# Why is my xsl processing instruction missing a question mark?

Tags: xslt

I want to create a html document with a php block (just for learning purposes) from an xsl transformation of a xml document.  I am using the `<xsl:processing-instruction>` tag.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="php">
    <xsl:text>
        setcookie("cookiename", "cookievalue");
        echo "";
    </xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        </head>
        <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="pagina">
    <xsl:for-each select="paragraf">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is:

```
<?php 
        setcookie("ceva", "textceva");
        echo "";>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
        text 1
    </p>
    <p>
        text 2
    </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why is the second question mark missing? I was expecting something like `<?php setcookie(...).. ?>` .

Comment: Seems to work fine when I try it. What XSLT processor are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your pi (processing instruction) is an SGML processing instruction (HTML is SGML). Normally the default output for XSLT is XML, but whatever processor that you're using must be defaulting to HTML (or you omitted something in your XSLT example). Another clue pointing to this is that your `meta` elements aren't closed in the output.

Example (note the `method="html"`):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <xsl:processing-instruction name="test">pi</xsl:processing-instruction>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output** (using the XSLT as the input (or any XML file))

```
<html><?test pi></html>
```

To force an XML pi, add the `xsl:output`:

```
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
```

Comment: The specified default is html if the top level element os html in no-namespace, as it is here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks David. I thought so, but wasn't sure enough to say so.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that the correct representation of a processing instruction in HTML is (or was, at the relevant point in time) to omit the question mark, and the specification for XSLT serialization says that this is what should be done by the HTML output method. Sorry, I don't have time to consult the specs just now to confirm this.

Of course, you are trying to generate stuff which is defined in the PHP specification rather than the HTML specification, and the XSLT serialization spec knows nothing of PHP.